# Apply styling created with jQuery to newly created elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to apply existing jQuery-created styling to elements that are created.  IE, if I style my elements as such:

```
$('a.something').css('background-color', 'black');
```

I want that styling to apply if I were to create another a.something via

```
$('#blah').append('<a href="#" class="something">stuff</a>');
```

I looked at the .live() function but it didn't seem to do exactly what I wanted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Has your question been resolved? Is there anything further we could do to assist?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to simply use jQuery to apply an already-existing class name to an object, rather than using the `.css()` method; that way any newly created elements, given that class-name, will automatically be assigned that styling.

Answer (score 0):

I think David Thomas has the right answer, but if you really wanted to do what you're saying, you could just put that `$('a.something').css('background-color', 'black');` into a function and call it after the append.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like addClass() ?
ex: $(".class").addClass("newclass");

Comment: You might want to take a read of the [mark-down/editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) to see how to format inline-code. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all links with the class of "something" to have a black background you should specify that in your CSS not in your jQuery. Moving this to your class and using

`$('<a href="#">stuff</a>').addClass("something").appendTo('#blah');`

is the more obvious solution to me.